# Convert array-of-strings to array-of-type

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an array of strings that are valid dates and I want to convert them into an array of dates.

Is there a more straightforward way to do the following in BigQuery?

```
SELECT CAST(['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'] AS ARRAY<date>)
```

Currently, I'm having to do the following workaround:

```
SELECT ARRAY(select cast(_ as date) FROM UNNEST((select ["2014-01-01", "2015-01-01"])) _)
```

The input/output should be:

```
IN:  ["2014-01-01", "2015-01-01"] 
--> 
OUT: [DATE "2014-01-01", DATE "2015-01-01"]
```

Comment: please clarify! so, let's say you have initial array of string and now you want to transform it into array of dates? is this the case?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes, exactly. How to get: `["2014-01-01"]` into `[DATE "2014-01-01"]`

Comment: I think the way you do is the only way - `select array_strings, array(select date(_) from t.array_strings _) array_dates 
from your_table as t` obviously assuming those strings are dates, otherwise you do that extra `safe_cast(_ as date) `. Note `safe_cast` not just `cast`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: I don't feel my above comments really qualified as an answer :o( they are just comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a filed [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/160100641) for this function. You may click on `+1` to bring more attention to the feature request and also `STAR` it for you to be notified for the updates.

Currently, there is no other workaround to achieve this other than what you mentioned.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(select cast(_ as date) FROM UNNEST((select ["2014-01-01", "2015-01-01"])) _)
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.